# Remove outliers from Raster

Tags: r, raster, boxplot, outliers

I was wondering if it's possible to remove outliers from Raster dataset [Data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DAh2Orn0J0Zk4N2k5drfS9iCwomDvtPt)

```
> library (raster)
> ras <- raster("08_sa.tif")
> boxplot(ras)
> summary(ras)
            08_sa.tif
Min.    -6.010734e+17
1st Qu. -4.292327e+15
Median   3.456345e+15
3rd Qu.  5.913508e+15
Max.     3.954778e+17
NA's     0.000000e+00

> dput(ras)
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
    ), offset = 0, gain = 1, inmemory = TRUE, fromdisk = FALSE, 
        isfactor = FALSE, attributes = list(), haveminmax = TRUE, 
        min = 213381595136, max = 395477771117133824, band = 1L, 
        unit = "", names = "Data"), legend = new(".RasterLegend", 
        type = character(0), values = logical(0), color = logical(0), 
        names = logical(0), colortable = logical(0)), title = character(0), 
    extent = new("Extent", xmin = 60.514678955, xmax = 97.416931152, 
        ymin = -0.701358795, ymax = 38.49804306), rotated = FALSE, 
    rotation = new(".Rotation", geotrans = numeric(0), transfun = function () 
    NULL), ncols = 369L, nrows = 392L, crs = new("CRS", projargs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"), 
    history = list(), z = list())
```

[image]

```
> as.data.frame(ras,xy=TRUE) -> df.ras
> colnames(df.ras) <- c("x","y","value")
> df.ras$value[!df.ras$value %in% boxplot.stats(df.ras$value)$out] -> no.outliner
> boxplot(no.outliner)
> plot(no.outliner)
> summary(no.outliner)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max.      NA's 
2.134e+11 3.315e+15 5.084e+15 4.936e+15 6.538e+15 1.145e+16    113153
```

[image: Without Outlier]
[image: Plot without Outlier 'no.outlier']
Without outlier 'no.outlier' has lost it geographical location
[image: Plot of 'ras' with outlier]
Plot of 'ras' before removing outliers

Comment: could you post 08_sa.tif?

Comment: it is posted in the link Data

Comment: A link for downloading data isn't good practice. Please use either `dput` if possible, or generate a small test dataset that reproduces your issue/question

Comment: @val that was test dataset only 234 kb in size. Question updated with dput.

Comment: @Dipu it's not about size, just making it easy (and safe) for people to help you. BTW, please post the output of `dput(ras)` not `dput(ras[1:10, 1:10])`

Comment: Dimension of Data is 392 x 369..i have inserted last few lines only in question of ```dput(ras)```

Answer (score 2):

I look at the histogram and boxplot,  noted the outliers range and deleted using reclassify. Thanks again @val your tip to reclassify is worth in r.

```
> x1 <- reclassify(ras, cbind(1.5e+16,Inf, NA), right=FALSE) 
> spplot(x1)
> boxplot(x1)
> hist(x1)
```

[image: Without outliers]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In all humility I'm suggesting this small function in Python since there is no programming language specified in the question.

Based on an histogram with nb_bins it identifies the bin_values (min and max outlier values) where consecutive amount (consecutive_low_bins) of low occurence (low_occurence_value) bins is encountered. It can slice values symetrically, only high values or only low values (slicing_type= 'symetric, 'high' or 'low'). Then it writes a new sliced raster (sliced).

The advantage over previous answers is that it can detect noise and truly outlying values which may not be identified with interquartile range or boxplot.

```
def remove_outliers_from_raster(raster, band, nan_values, nb_bins, consecutive_low_bins, low_occurence_value,  slicing_type):
dataset=rasterio.open(raster)
band=dataset.read(band)
shape=band.shape
rave=np.ravel(band)
rave[rave == nan_values] = np.NAN
array=rave[~np.isnan(rave)]

bins, bin_values=np.histogram(array, bins=nb_bins)

cpt=0
compte=[]
for i in bins:
    if i<=low_occurence_value:
        cpt +=1
        compte.append(cpt)
    else:
        cpt=0
        compte.append(cpt)

compte=np.array(compte)
compte_min=compte[:math.ceil(len(compte)/2)]
compte_max=compte[math.floor(-len(compte)/2):]

try:
    tresh_bin_min=np.where(compte_min>=consecutive_low_bins)[0][-1]
    tresh_value_min=bin_values[tresh_bin_min]
except:
    tresh_bin_min=0
    tresh_value_min=-99999999

try:
    tresh_bin_max=len(compte_min)+np.where(compte_max>=consecutive_low_bins)[0][0]-consecutive_low_bins
    tresh_value_max=bin_values[tresh_bin_max]
except:
    tresh_bin_max=0
    tresh_value_max=99999999
    
print(tresh_bin_min, tresh_value_min, tresh_bin_max, tresh_value_max)

rave2=np.ravel(band)

if slicing_type == 'low':   
    rave2=np.where(rave2 > tresh_value_min, rave2, -3.2768e+04)
elif slicing_type == 'high':
    rave2=np.where((rave2 < tresh_value_max), rave2, -3.2768e+04)
else:
    rave2=np.where((rave2 < tresh_value_max) & (rave2 > tresh_value_min), rave2, -3.2768e+04)

band2=rave2.reshape(shape)

kwargs=dataset.meta

with rasterio.open(path, 'w', **kwargs) as dst:
    dst.write_band(1, band2.astype(rasterio.float64))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
# load package raster
library(raster)

# load your data
ras <- raster("08_sa.tif")

# make a df
as.data.frame(ras,xy=TRUE) -> df.ras

# adjust col names
colnames(df.ras) <- c("x","y","value")

# remove outliner
df.ras$value[!df.ras$value %in% boxplot.stats(df.ras$value)$out] -> no.outliner

# draw boxplot without outliner 
boxplot(no.outliner)
```

Comment: i think it removed the outliers but lost its geographical location

Answer (score -1):

Try **autooptimizer** module

```py
pip install autooptimizer

from autooptimizer.process import outlier_removal
```